# How to prove (if it is even needed) if $ac \leq bc$, then $a \leq b$ using Peano axioms

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, peano-axioms

I would like to know about the properties of inequalities in Peano arithmetic. Do they need to be proven or are they true by definition? Especially the following two properties:

1. if $ac \leq bc$, then $a \leq b$,
2. if $a + c \leq b + c$, then $a \leq b$.

Comment: Use induction on $c$. Simple and easy.

Comment: @DHMO:  Which, of course, fails for the base case, $c=0$, so start with $c=1$ as the base

Comment: I guess their $\Bbb N$ does not include $0$ @JasonDeVito

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please read the [how-to-ask page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?). In particular, it would be much better if your question contained more detail on the motivation for your question as well as what you've found out or tried so far. Even if it's just curiosity. This helps people to give appropriate answers that you can understand. At first glance, it seems you're curious to know how much needs to be assumed and how much can be proven. It turns out that all you need is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $c =0$ we have $ac \le bc$ for *any* $a$, and $b$ ... So I assume that what you really want to prove is:

$\forall a \forall b \forall c (c \not = 0 \rightarrow (ac \le bc \rightarrow a \le b))$

Now, to do this, you might think that induction on $c$ would be able to do this fairly quickly, but that is not true. In fact, compared to the method I suggest, induction would only add unnecessary lines to the proof.

Instead, use Trichotomy: $\forall a \forall b ( a < b \lor a = b \lor b<a)$

together with the basic definition of $< $ or $\le$, whichever you have defined.

First prove $\forall a \forall b \forall c (c \not =0 \rightarrow (a < b\rightarrow ac < bc))$, which is easy to do: If $c \not = 0$ and $a < b$, then $a + s(d) = b$ for some $d$, and $c = s(e)$ for some $e$. Thus: $ac = as(e) = ae + a < ae + s(d)e + a + s(d) =(a + s(d))e + a + s(d)=(a+s(d))s(e)=bc$.

Once you have that, you can prove $\forall a \forall b \forall c (c \not = 0 \rightarrow (ac \le bc \rightarrow a \le b))$ by assuming $ac \le bc$, and then ruling out $b < a$ given what you just proved (you'll also need asymmetry and irreflexivity of $<$). So, if $b<a$ is ruled out then $a \le b$ using Trichotomy. If you don't have Trichotomy, you can prove Trichotomy using Induction.

To prove that $\forall a \forall b \forall c (a+c \le b +c \rightarrow a \le b)$, again first prove its 'converse': $\forall a \forall b \forall c ( a <b \rightarrow a +c < b +c)$. This is easy to do: If $a < b$, then $a + s(d) = b$ for some $d$, and hence $(a + s(d)) + c = b + c$, and thus by Association $(a + c) + s(d) = b + c$, and so $a + c < b + c$.

Once you have that, the proof for $\forall a \forall b \forall c (a+c \le b +c \rightarrow a \le b)$ is as follows: assume $a + c \le b + c$. Then if $b < a$ you get $b +c  < a + c$ which by asymmetry and irreflexivity of $<$ means that $\neg (a + c \le b + c)$ and hence you get a contradiction. Hence, $\neg b < a$, and so by Trichotomy you are left with $a \le b$.

Comment: Actually we won't get stuck, because if $a>b$ then $a(c+1) \le b(c+1)$ implies $ac+a \le bc+b < bc+a$ and hence $ac < bc$ by trichotomy and LEM. This plus induction yields a proof. Its core is essentially the same as your proof's. =)

Comment: @user21820 Right ... I should have put that differently; it's that in this case induction doesn't help in comparison with the method I suggest; it only adds more lines to the proof.

Comment: I didn't check, but yea I too believe that attempting induction right from the beginning won't shorten the proof.

Comment: I really can't see how to do ∀a∀b∀c(a+c≤b+c→a≤b) by induction.

Comment: @GabrielCorso No, don't to that one by induction, but you can do its 'converse' by induction: $\forall a \forall b (a < b \rightarrow a +c < b + c)$ ... Although you can probably prove that one in a more direct proof as well: if $a < b$ then $a + s(d) = b$ for some $d$, and therefore $(a +s(d) ) + c = b+c$, and so (using Association) $(a +c) + s(d ) =b + d$, and hence $a +c < b+ d$. And once you have this converse, go from $a+c \le b +c$ to $a \le b$ using Trichotomy, ruling out $b < a$ as an option, for then $b+c < a+c$ using the Converse you just proved and that contradicts $a +c \le b +c$